# JavaScript promises, resolve , reject

Tags: javascript, promise

So I was wondering what's going on with the response and reject object of a prommise.
I was reading this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
And there are things that are quite unclear to me.

For example what is the `resolve()` object all about.

I've seen that this thing can have inside a string and then the `resolve()` gets launched ? 
What's going on and what's the point of that

```
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    resolve('foo');
  }, 300);
});
```

I initially thought that the resolve function/object gets launched whenever the callback function returns a value
and then it can go on to `.then()`

So I've been playing around for a while with this thing and it turns out that my theory with resolve on return works 50 % of the time, the other 50% crashing my mind.

Also the reject object/function, how do u launch it when let's say the outcome of a function is 0 but it had to be 1 so I can continue ?

```
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   if(someFunction() === 0)
   {
     reject();
   } else {
     resolve()
   }
});
```

This code only works when inside my `someFunction()` I don't have any asynchronous functions and well, when I do have any , it always returns undefined.

So up to this point the point of the concept of promise and its use it's quite unclear to me.

Comment: If you call `resolve('some value')` inside `new Promise((resolve, reject)=>...)`, it will pass `'some value'` into the `.then()` callback. If you call `reject('some error')` it will do the same but for the `.catch()` callback, and won't call `.then()`

Comment: Whenever `someFunction()` is async, you need to use `if (await someFunction()` and your promise param function should be async as well.

Comment: `resolve` and `reject` are functions, not just objects. _“I initially thought that the `resolve` function […] gets launched whenever the callback function returns a value and then it can go on to `.then()`”_ — by “callback function” do you mean the function within `new Promise(`…`)`? `return` is one way to advance to `.then`, but sometimes it’s impossible to return (e.g. nested event based functions); that’s when `resolve` is used.

Comment: @George _“and won’t call `.then()`”_ — `then` accepts two arguments. In case of an error, the second one will be called.

Comment: I have found this blog useful https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/callbacks-promises-and-async-await-ad4756e01d90

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right about the fact that the resolve function (and oh they are functions ) get's launched whenever the callback function returns a value.

In the case you showed up, the value returned its 'foo'

Even if its not a function having it there like that it's the equivalent of having a function return something.
So to that point everything is good.

The fact that it does' not work when the callback function is having any piece of asynchronous code, its just because as you, say'd it returns undefined.
The function hasn't finished running so it returns that.
It doesn't wait for it .
The simplest solution I can think of that would solve both of you'r problems is to pass the resolve and reject object to the callback function and launch them from the inside

For example

```
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   someFunction(resolve,reject);
});

function someFunction(resolve,reject){
  var i = 0;
  setTimeout(function() {
    if(i===0){
      reject(/**You can even pass it some variables here if u wanted*/);
    } else {
      resolve(/**Same here*/); // this should work just fine and it will sucesfully launch .then with whatever u need returned 
    }
  }, 300);
}
```